# JAX-RS error sending object containing Array to DELETE

Tags: angularjs, json, jax-rs

I am designing an application with an auction functionality. The frontend is in  Angularjs, and the backend uses JAX-RS on Glassfish 4.

I have a situation where I want to delete a number of auctions that a user is watching. I send an container object to the server which contains an array telling which auctions that I wish to delete for that user.

However, the server throws an error when I send that object. It is obviously not liking how it receives the object - it seems to be not being transposed correctly from the json to the JAVA object.

This is the what the object looks like when it is printed to the console before sending it from the angularJS frontend:

```
deleteAuctionWatchlistContainer = {"auctionWatchlistDeleteEntries":[{"auction_id":356,"user_id":2},{"auction_id":225,"user_id":2}]}
```

This is the error that is returned. As you can see from the config returns the array, but not the object containing it.

```
Error trying to delete the auction watchlist entries:
{"data":{"errorCode":500},"status":500,"config":        
    {"method":"DELETE","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],
    "auctionWatchlistDeleteEntries":[{"auction_id":356,"user_id":2},{"auction_id":225,"user_id":2}],
    "url":"http://localhost:8080/pododdle/webapi/users/2/auctionwatchlist",
    "headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},
"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

I have used container objects before for doing this sort of thing, but can't see why it doesn't work this time. I can see that the resource is getting called correctly, but once the resource tries to covert the json to the java object it throws the error.

The JAVA model for the container looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DeleteAuctionWatchlistsContainer {

    private AuctionWatchlistEntry[] auctionWatchlistDeleteEntries;

    public DeleteAuctionWatchlistsContainer() {

    }

    public AuctionWatchlistEntry[] getAuctionWatchlistDeleteEntries() {
        return auctionWatchlistDeleteEntries;
    }
}
```

The Java for the AuctionWatchlistEntry model is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AuctionWatchlistEntry {

    private int auction_id;
    private int user_id;

    public AuctionWatchlistEntry() {

    }

    public int getAuction_id() {
        return auction_id;
    }

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
}
```

Here is the JAX-RS resource for the auction watchlist delete:

```
@DELETE
public Response deleteAuctionWatchlists(DeleteAuctionWatchlistsContainer dAWC)
{
    return Response.ok(auctionWatchlistService.deleteAuctionWatchlistEntries(dAWC.getAuctionWatchlistDeleteEntries()).toString()).build();
}
```

The angularjs method which sends the object to the server is held inside a angularjs service. Here is where we call the service method:

```
var deleteAuctionWatchlistContainer = { auctionWatchlistDeleteEntries: deleteEntries };
pododdle.deleteAuctionWatchlistEntries(deleteAuctionWatchlistContainer).then(onDeleteAuctionWatchlistEntriesComplete, onDeleteAuctionWatchlistEntriesError);
```

Here is the service method code:

```
var deleteAuctionWatchlistEntries = function(deleteAuctionWatchlistContainer) {
    return $http.delete("http://localhost:8080/pododdle/webapi/users/" + currentUser.user_id + "/auctionwatchlist", deleteAuctionWatchlistContainer)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    })          
};
```

All help much appreciated. Please let me know if I have ommitted anything relevant...

Comment: Are you using jackson to map jaxb annotations to json? Have you registered the json provider? Why DeleteAuctionWatchlistsContainer has not XmlRootElement annotation? What is saying server log?

Comment: I have added to the XmlRootElement to the DeleteAuctionWatchlistContainer - that was a good spot. But the error remains the same. The Resource which contains the @DELETE method has the @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON). The server log is not reporting anything at all. I have some System.out.println's inside the delete method which print, but it doesn't do anything once it tries to access the Container object....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by @DELETE not accepting an entity. To get around this, I used a query parameter which included a delimited string of auction_id's I want to delete for the particular use.

I do know if this is too much of hack, but it works fine and suits the desired behaviour of the user.